# Is the following subspace of $l^2$ complete?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

The problem is the following:

Consider the set $$G_2=\{(x_n)\in l_2: \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n=0\}\subset l_2 $$
Is $(G_2,d_2)$ a complete metric space?

$l_2=\{(x_n): \left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n|^2\right)^{1/2}<\infty\}$

$d_2((x_n),(y_n))=\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n-y_n|^2\right)^{1/2}$

My approach-guess:

In order to prove that this subset of $l_2$ is a complete metric space one needs to find its closure (then $G_2$ is dense in $l^2$), something that did not work so well for me. My guess is that this set is not complete subspace of $l^2$ but I have no idea how to show this. I tried to find a counter-example but I failed. Any help from you would be appreciated!

Comment: If $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty x_n$ doesn't exist, do you consider $x_n$ to be in $G_2$?

Comment: No it will not belong to $G^2$

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio I think it works because we take a sequence which belongs to $G^2$ and it has it's $\ell^2$ norm tending to infinity when $N\to \infty $. So our subspace is not complete. Right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $S^{(N)}$ be the sequence such that $x_0=-1$ and $x_n=\frac{1}{N}$ for any $N+1\leq n\leq 2N$, zero otherwise.
This sequence belongs to $G_2$ and $\{S^{(N)}\}_{N\geq 1}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\ell^2$, but $\lim_{N\to \infty}S^{(N)}$ is not a zero-sum sequence. This disproves completeness.

Comment: This works properly! Thanks for that , I appreciate it :)

Comment: @KennyWong: it looks to me that this setup works, indeed. We have: $$\left\|S^{(N)}-S^{(M)}\right\|_2 \leq \sqrt{\frac{1}{N}+\frac{1}{M}} \leq \sqrt{\frac{2}{\min(N,M)}}$$ proving that $\{S^{(N)}\}_{N\geq 1}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\ell^2$.

Comment: You nailed it :P

Comment: Yes, I'm convinced! It's a lovely example, like I said.

Answer (score 4):

To work out the closure of $G_2$, we could use the fact that $\bar{G_2} = (G_2^\perp)^{\perp}$.

But $G_2^\perp = \{ 0 \}$. [For instance, if $y_n \in G_2^{\perp}$, then the fact that $y_n$ is perpendicular to $(1,-1,0,0, \dots)$, $(0,1, -1,0, \dots)$, $(0,0, 1,-1, \dots), \dots$ means that $y_1 = y_2 = y_3 = \dots$, and the only way that such a $y_n$ can be $l^2$ normalisable is if $y_1 = y_2 = y_3 = \dots = 0$.]

Hence $\bar{G_2} = \{ 0 \}^{\perp} = l^2 \neq G_2$, so $G_2$ is not closed, and hence, not complete.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but I am new to functional analysis ( this is our 9th excercise for this semester ) and I sadly don't understand fully your answer . Thanks though for your interest, I will upvote and if there is not an easier answer to my question I will accept it. Thanks for your effort :)

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. I think you could have understood it if I explained it better. If $A$ is a subset of a Hilbert space $H$, then $A^\perp$ simply means the set of all elements of $H$ that are perpendicular to every element in $A$. It's a standard fact that the closure of the linear span of $A$ is equal to $(A^\perp)^\perp$. I'm sure it will be in your course.

Comment: We are currently seeing more topological things like completeness conpactness and other stuff like these. So I guess my professor wants a solution involving only these stuff he showed to us. I know a bit of what I am about to see in this course but I like to take things step by step. I think he seeks for a counter example . Thanks again :D